# Highcharts make all datalabels to the left of donut chart

Tags: javascript, css, charts, highcharts

I am trying to get all the data labels to be on the left side of the donut chart. How may I do that?

This is what it currently looks like
[image: This is what it currently looks like]

This is what I want
[image]

Thanks!

Comment: Can you add a http://jsfiddle.net or post your code

Comment: You should accompany your question with a little research of where you encountered problems

Answer (score 0):

Try with the X property of datalabels

http://jsfiddle.net/00u0borL/

```
dataLabels: { 
enabled: true,
format: '<b>{point.name}</b>: {point.percentage:.1f} %',
x: '-200'
```

Comment: Thanks so much! Is there a way to make the lines join up to the labels too?

Comment: check the `connectorPadding` property